# Clone Gitlab repo without password

Tags: git, http, gitlab

Is there a way I can allow others to clone source via http from a public repo I'm hosting without requiring a password?

It currently prompts for a password which fails if I try to do `http://username:password@<repolocation>.git`, so people are having to set up SSH keys just to clone the source.

Is there a better way to do this? I'm fairly new to git & gitlab so I'm not really sure where to look.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Since **[GitLab 6.2](http://blog.gitlab.org/gitlab-ce-6-dot-2-released/)**, it should be possible; since you can define a project as "public", like those [GitLab public project](https://gitlab.com/public).

That was recently completed (October 2013) in this [feedback request](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3159951-allow-public-repositories).

Comment: I've set my project as Public in the settings, yet it's still requiring a password. I'm stumped as to why. I know that I've personally cloned from other projects without a password, not sure why it's not working here.

Comment: @redFIVE are you using an http or https url? And are you keeping a '`username`' in the `https://username@<server>/repo.git` url? Because if you do, that would compel `curl` (used by `git clone`) to ask for a password.

Comment: I'm using http. Without username@server it just asks for the default git@ password, which doesn't work. Same if I do use username@server, it prompts for password

Comment: Note that the public repos from gitlab are all using https url, as in `git clone https://gitlab.com/adambrenecki/test-project.git`. Could you use a similar schema for your public repo url?

Comment: I'm using the url gitlab provided for http. If I try https I get a `SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate` error. @vonC im able to check out your's just fine

Answer (score 1):

This was puzzling to me. I had to set **two** settings: the Project visibility (Public) and the Repository access (changed to "Everyone with access").

(other [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43770960/1506338))